# Update linked server table based on local table

Tags: sql-server-2014, update, linked-server

i'm trying to update a remote table using linked server, based on id of my local table.

I'm trying this:

```
update [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2
                set [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.cod = tabela1.codigo
                from [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2 
                    join tabela1 
                    on tabela1.id=[HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.id
```

> The multi-part identifier
>   "HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01.dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.id" could not be bound.

i tried to update the local server based on the linked server but I still receive errors like `the TABLE_NAME could not be bound`.

```
update tabela1 
        set tabela1 .cod=[HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.cod
            from [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2 
            join tabela1 
            on [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.id=tabela1.id
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 40 The multi-part identifier
>   "HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01.dba_teste.dbo.tabela2.cod" could not be bound.

There's a lot of questions like this one on stackoverflow but none of them is working.

tabela1=local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant have 5 identifiers, this should do the trick

```
UPDATE T2
SET    T2.cod = T1.codigo
FROM   [HQSQLHOM01\SQLHOM01].dba_teste.dbo.tabela2 AS T2
JOIN   tabela1 AS T1
       ON T1.id = T2.id
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190406(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Wow it worked. thank you! I think I should know that already.

Comment: I just need to use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` because i'm tyring to use `begin tran`.